# nth-child of CSS3 columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns, css-selectors

I'm using [CSS3 columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) but i want to control each column individually to set different backgrounds to even / odd columns.

I want the result to be as shown in this picture:

[image: Wanted result]

The html content:

```
<div id="content">
    content body text content body text content body text 
    content body text content body text content body text content body text
    content body text content body text content body text content body text
    content body text content body text content body text content body text 
    content body text content body text content body text content body text 
    content body text content body text content body text content body text 
    content body text content body text content body text content body text 
</div>
```

Css:

```
#content {
   column-gap:25px;
   column-count:3;
}
```

I want to use something like:

```
column:nth-child(even)
{
   background:#0000ff;
}
```

Can i use [CSS3 :nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) property? or can i use any javascript solution to get selector of any individual column?

Please give your suggested solutions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Add absolute positioned background blocks for styling..

Something like this:

```
#bg1 {
  position: absolute; 
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:green;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4fSC/1/)

Comment: Did you know that other rendering engines than WebKit support CSS3 columns?

Comment: @FelipeAls, with prefixes (-moz- for FF)

Comment: [For at least one browser, it doesn't work with a prefix but already works without](http://caniuse.com/#search=column). The other way around: your fiddle only works on WebKit. Not every webdeveloper works with a WebKit/Blink browser (did I shock anybody?) and same for final users.

Comment: @FelipeAls, answer is not a fiddle, fiddle is concept; SO should not become a place with ready solutions, we always should allow to think)

Comment: And question not about css3 columns directly

Comment: I? I get this link from a question above :)

Comment: Thank you @vp_arth for your temporary solution

Comment: @vp_arth: Nobody said anything about a ready-made solution. The point is that making all your answers specific to WebKit perpetuates the misguided notion that WebKit is some sort of standard reference implementation that we can all rely on and that it is the be-all and end-all to CSS. It is not; it is one of the worst examples there can be. And I don't see how the question *isn't* about CSS3 multi-column layout.

Comment: Nothing, I'm just clarifying what @FelipeAls said earlier.

Comment: All the fighting above aside, this is a great solution as to how to define background colors for each column.   Nice "workaround"!